# Active admin setup mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5

I am having a rails 5 application with mongoid .Looking forward to work with active admin but as I am looking from 2013 there is no support for active admin with mongoid [link](https://rubygems.org/gems/activeadmin-mongoid/versions/0.3.0) &&[github](https://github.com/elia/activeadmin-mongoid) . So can anyone tell me from where I can find compatible version of active admin or any other admin support for mongoid

This is my gem file

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.4.0'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'mongoid', git: 'https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid.git'
gem 'bson_ext'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'nodejs-rails', '~> 0.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'devise'
#gem 'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave-mongoid', :require => 'carrierwave/mongoid'
gem "mini_magick"
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'
gem 'twilio-ruby', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'city-state'
gem 'haversine', '~> 0.3.0'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'pry'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin

Comment: this is not compatible with mongoid